# Ordered sequences of integer with fixed sum

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $I_S = \{0, 1, \ldots, S\}$, with $S \geq 1$.

Consider all the ordered sequences of length $L \geq 2$ in $I_S^L$ such that the sum of all the terms is equal to $S$. Let $N(L,S)$ be the number of these sequences.

I'm struggling to derive $N(L,S)$. I would like at least some upper bound. Here is what I've done:

1. $N(2,S) = S+1$ (trivial)
2. $N(L+1,S) \leq (L+1)N(L,S)$ (this can be achieved by adding a zero between $2$ consecutive digits)
3. Then in general: 
   $$N(L,S) \leq \frac{L!}{2}(S+1)$$

This works, but maybe it's too much conservative.

For example, $N(2,2) = 3$, $N(3,2) = 6$, $N(4,2) = 10$, but $$N(3,2) \leq \frac{3\cdot2}{2}3 = 9$$
$$N(4,2) \leq \frac{4 \cdot 3\cdot2}{2}3 = 36$$

4. $N(L,1) = L$ (trivial)
5. $N(L,S+1) \leq \displaystyle L N(L,S)$ (sum $1$ to each element)
6. Then in general $N(L,S) \leq L^{S+1}$

For example, $N(3,1) = 3$, $N(3,2) = 6$, $N(3,3) = 10$. But:

$$N(3,2) \leq 3^3 = 27$$
$$N(3,3) \leq 3^4 = 81$$

Is there some better upper bound?

Actually, the best I can do is $$N(L,S) \leq \min \left\{L^{S+1}, \frac{L!}{2}(S+1)\right\}$$

Comment: Are you sure N(3,3)=12? I'm getting 10.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, thanks

Comment: The term "ordered sequence" is confusing. Since the terms of a sequence already appear in a given order, it would seem that you do not refer to that, but that instead you are only counting increasing (or decreasing, depending on your ordering preferences) sequences. From point (1) however I gather that you do not mean that. Why not just say "sequences"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your numbers in "unary representation" ($k$ is represented by $k$ digits $1$, in particular $0$ by an empty string) then your equation "$n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_L=S$" will have exactly $S+L-1$ symbols to the left of the "$=$", namely $S$ digits "$1$" and $L-1$ signs "$+$". Write $S+L-1$ digits $1$ and choose any $L-1$ of them to be transformed into $+$, for a total of
$$
  N(L,S)=\binom{S+L-1}{L-1}=\binom{S+L-1}S
$$
solutions. Some call this a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) argument (I would prefer "ones and plusses").

Comment: amazing and elegant! thank you very much!